# C/C++ printfs - Where's it appears in a Android native code?

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

Since It's pretty hard to debug native android code, I'm going to the "printf trace" approach.

So, my question is, in a native code, wheres the standards "printf("something")" appears when running a Android application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to see printf lines in gdb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459324/how-to-see-printf-lines-in-gdb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "std::cout" usable in Android-ndk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870174/is-stdcout-usable-in-android-ndk)

Comment: My question was from one year before @CiroSantilli刘晓波死六四事件法轮功

Comment: Hi Marcos, the current consensus is to close by "quality": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha Since "quality" is not measurable, I just go by upvotes. ;-) Likely it comes down to which question hit the best newbie Google keywords on the title.

Comment: Not willing to improve the question quality though? The other question is about the physical space where the log appears to, I'm asking how to see in logcat.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Log to logcat.

1) To invoke the logger in native code include the header and call _android_log_write(..).

```
#include <android/log.h>

__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "tag here", "message here");
```

2) In your Android.mk file include the log lib like this.

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
```

Comment: what is the (SYSROOT)/usr/lib?

Comment: perfect ! On a side note, this works even without editing the .mk on my test case.

Comment: In my case `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog` didn't work. I had to use `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are shorter macros available in order to log to logcat.

```
#define LOG_TAG "my_log_tag"
#include <cutils/log.h>

ALOGD("Format this %d", some_int);
```

In Android.mk, add the `liblog` library to `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` when building in 'mydroid' (full android system build). In case of ndk build `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog` can be used.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := foo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo.c
# if mydroid
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog
# in ndk, use LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog instead
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

There are various other macros defined for all levels of logging. From `cutils/log.h`:

```
#define ALOGV(...) ((void)ALOG(LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))
#define ALOGD(...) ((void)ALOG(LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))
...
#define ALOGE(...) ((void)ALOG(LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))
```

Comment: I did all the above suggestions. but, i still get undefined reference to '__android_log_write'. Any new solutions?