# javah jni generated header has syntax error - Android NDK - eclipse

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native, android-ndk

Android NDK, I used the following command to generate the jni header,

```
C:\eclipse_workspace\C_Google_FaceDetect\bin>javah -jni -verbose -classpath C:\Android_SDK\platforms\android-10;C:\eclipse_workspace\C_Google_FaceDetect\src;. -d C:\eclipse_workspace\C_Google_FaceDetect\jni c.google.facedetect.FaceDetect
```

The problem is
even though I set everything well, I'm getting the following error

> No implementation found for native Lc/google/facedetect/FaceDetect;.decodeYUV([I[BII)V
>
> threadid=1:thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
>
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: decodeYUV

I tried looking for what's wrong, and I found that in the c_google_facedetect_FaceDetect.h jni header file, I have a syntax error actually (even though it's generated)

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h> /* Header for class c_google_facedetect_FaceDetect */

#ifndef _Included_c_google_facedetect_FaceDetect
#define _Included_c_google_facedetect_FaceDetect
#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" {
#endif
#undef c_google_facedetect_FaceDetect_CAMERA_WIDTH
#define c_google_facedetect_FaceDetect_CAMERA_WIDTH 480L
#undef c_google_facedetect_FaceDetect_CAMERA_HEIGHT
#define c_google_facedetect_FaceDetect_CAMERA_HEIGHT 320L
/*
* Class:     c_google_facedetect_FaceDetect
* Method:    decodeYUV
* Signature: ([I[BII)V
*/

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_c_google_facedetect_FaceDetect_decodeYUV(JNIEnv *, jobject, jintArray, jbyteArray, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus }
#endif
#endif
```

The "JNIEXPORT void JNICALL ...." line has a syntax error, maybe that's what causing all the errors ?

My Android.mk file is as follows:

> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
> LOCAL_MODULE    := face-detect
>
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := face-detect.c
>
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

**UPDATE**
My one and only java file is called FaceDetect.java and includes the following code

```
public class FaceDetect extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback
{
static
    {
        Log.d("mytag", "before_lib");
        System.loadLibrary("face-detect");
        Log.d("mytag", "after_lib");
    }
public static native void decodeYUV(int[] out, byte[] fg, int width, int height);
}
```

Also, Eclipse doesn't say what the syntax error is, it only underlines the JNIExport line and says syntax error

**Another UPDATE to answer the question**
I have indeed checked that the library is being loaded, here is the logcat

07-16 13:31:43.257: D/mytag(25188): before_lib 
07-16 13:31:43.281: D/dalvikvm(25188): Trying to load lib /data/data/c.google.facedetect/lib/libface-detect.so 0x40517808 
07-16 13:31:43.281: D/dalvikvm(25188): Added shared lib /data/data/c.google.facedetect/lib/libface-detect.so 0x40517808 
07-16 13:31:43.281: D/dalvikvm(25188): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/c.google.facedetect/lib/libface-detect.so 0x40517808, skipping init 
07-16 13:31:43.281: D/mytag(25188): after_lib

Comment: Eclipse doesn't give any more details, it just says syntax error on that line

Comment: Eclipse is often wrong.  It doesn't like C code if it's not pointed at a full set of headers, and with the latest ADT release it is just *randomly* wrong / stale about Java code a lot of the time.  See if you can disable the checking, or cut what it is complaining about, save, and clean, then paste it back in.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thank you for your comment, so I should ignore this syntax error ? but then why do I keep getting that "no implementation found error"

Comment: Try running nkd-build from the commandline according to the ndk docs.  If that works and generates a library, eclipse is wrong (though it may fail to update you project until you get it to stop checking).  But if ndk-build fails, then you may really have an answer.

Comment: ndk-build from cygwin bash works perfectly fine and generates the .so file.
the java header that has the syntax error is generated by the javah command mentioned in the question.

Comment: the only reason I'm bothered with this syntax error, is that it may solve the riddle of the "no implementation found" error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax error. Check that you are loading your native library and that it has loaded successfuly.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Writing code in comments is a bit rough, I updated the question, if you can please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: I have checked that the library is being loaded and updated the question to include the code and the logcat :D

Comment: Implement JNI_OnLoad and do something observable in it, to be 100% sure that your lib is added correctly. Also dump the symbols exported by your libface-detect.so and post it here.

Comment: how do I implement JNI_OnLoad ? please advise

Comment: [Like this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/other.html#30439). The only mandatory part is returning the minimal supported JNI version. Most probably you would like to [print something into logcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426911/c-c-printfs-wheres-it-appears-in-a-android-native-code).