# Android Native Code Debugging

Tags: android, android-ndk

How can I get the cout output of the native c++ program on the log-cat in android application development in eclipse.

Please someone help me here.

Comment: You can enable checkJNI [More on this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/debugging-android-jni-with-checkjni.html)

Comment: Is there a way to get the standard output of native c++array code to log-cat.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426911/c-c-printfs-wheres-it-appears-in-a-android-native-code check this link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531050/redirect-stdout-to-logcat-in-android-ndk

Answer (score 5):

The stdout/stderr file descriptors are sent to `/dev/null` in Android apps.  (The Java equivalents, `System.out` and `System.err`, are redirected to the log by the app framework.)

The Dalvik VM includes a hack that will let you see stdout/stderr on a rooted device by setting the `log.redirect-stdio` property.  See [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#viewingStd) for details.  It works by starting a thread that reads from the stdio file descriptors and copies the data to the logging system.

For new code, it's much easier to use the Android log calls directly.  If you're importing a library from elsewhere, of course, it's a bit harder.  If necessary you could copy [the code out of Dalvik](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/master/vm/StdioConverter.cpp) and into your app and have it do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for this - that's apparently what happens- but why the docs say : "By default, the Android system sends stdout and stderr _(System.out and System.err)_ output to /dev/null." (emphasis mine). See : http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#viewingStd

Comment: The docs are wrong.  I filed https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62555 .

Comment: interesting fadden :)