# Which differences are among System.err/out, e.printStackTrace and log for android Exception?

Tags: android, logging

I am a little confused to differenate System.err/out, e.printStackTrace and log while logging RuntimeException.

At first, I thought that log information is not saved in a file if I use System.err/out, e.printStackTrace and just printed on console.

But System.err/out, e.printStackTrace also seem to be logged in a log buffer and we can see it through logcat.

Threfore, if we can save log in a file and also System.err/out, e.printStackTrace results can saved in a file.

Q1. What I understand is right?

Q2. If it is, which logging type is better to debug field issues after production?

Q3. If any RuntimeExceptions occur, where can I find the log file in android folder?

**UPDATE**

I got an answer for Q3.

In case of android, RuntimeException log seems to be saved in /data/system/dropbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Android, it's more efficient to log exceptions and write messages using the methods in `Log`. In emulators and on most devices, writing directly to `System.out` or `System.err` get redirected to `Log.i`. On some devices, writes to `System.out/err` are lost. From the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#viewingStd):

> By default, the Android system sends `stdout` and `stderr` (`System.out` and `System.err`) output to `/dev/null`.

Using `e.printStackTrace` also just writes to `System.err`, and I believe that it is less informative than the `Log` methods, since you can add a log tag to the latter.

As far as I know, all the logging information, including output from app crashes, is kept in the logs. (If you catch `RuntimeException`s, there is no output unless your code generates it.) You can find the logs, I believe, in `/system/bin/logcat`; however, it's not in plain text format. You can pull the information off the device in a readable form by attaching it to a development environment and entering the command:

```
adb logcat -d -v time > logfile.txt
```

There's also a logcat view in Eclipse. There are also some free utilities ([aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en) and [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en) come to mind) for looking at the logcat data on a device.

Comment: When I write something like `System.out.println("test");` in my java code I see it printed in the logcat in eclipse - I do not remember setting any options there - does this not contradict the docs ? (NB: I have my device plugged in in my PC) see also : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17199704/281545

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D - By default, System.out is routed to /dev/null, but with additional configuration it can be sent to logcat. I believe that the emulators do that additional configuration on their own. If you debug an app on a real device through Eclipse, you may or may not see System.out output in logcat, depending on the device.

Answer (score 1):

> What I understand is right?

Your understanding seems fine. Most things written to standard output or error are displayed in Logcat. As Ted Hopp noted, though, it's preferable to use the `Log` class for logging. This information is not saved to an easily-accessed file by default, but you could perform that step yourself.

> If it is, which logging type is better to debug field issues after production?

It's difficult to collect debugging information if you're storing it on the device in a file. If you're deploying your app to the Google Play Store, you can use the Developer Console to view stack traces from your app (provided that your users have opted to send crash reports). A more reliable solution would be to use a service that tracks crashes in the wild and aggregates a lot of useful statistics for you (e.g., Crittercism).

> If any RuntimeExceptions occur, where can I find the log file in android folder?

They're not stored in a log file, as far as I know. You could catch each exception and write something to a custom log file (whose location you can choose), but that tends to be unwieldy; the services that I mentioned above will be much more efficient for doing this.